# Mustache how to access specific element of array in arraylist

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I have an arraylist "Numlist" with 10 Objects ,

in each Object there's an String[10] array "Num".

How can I access and show a specific string (for ex: Num[8]) ?

So it's a .mustache file , with html and javascripts.
I have an arraylist "Numlist" with 10 Objects ,
Each Object contains a String "name" , and a String[10] "Num"

I can easily access and show "name" use `{{name}}` , 
But I can not use {{Num.0}} which method I found online ,
to access and show the string in "Num[0]" ,

```
{{#Numlist}}
          <div class="data-table">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td >{{name}}</td>
                    <td >{{Num.0}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
{{/Numlist}}
```

I expect the output should be a table like
**[ name ][String in Num[0]]**
But I only got
**[ name ][ ]**
It seems {{Num.0}} does not work at all.

Is there a another way to access specific element in array ,
or just i use {{num.0}} this method wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Array elements are accessed with bracket notation - an error is thrown if you use dot notation:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arr..2);
```

Use `[0]`:

```
{{Num[0]}}
```

Comment: I not familiar with mustache , but as i search online , mustache does not support using Num[0].

Comment: Then what is `Num`?

Comment: Num is a array string[10] , but in mustache there's no bracket  notation can use